# Error: LateInitializationError: Local 'command' has not been initialized. Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Getting this error in debug console. Is it causing my widget inspector to malfunction as well?

```
Error: LateInitializationError: Local 'command' has not been initialized.
at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:63463/dart_sdk.js:5041:11)
at command$35get (http://localhost:63463/dart_sdk.js:170859:41)
at _engine.TextEditingChannel.new.handleTextInput (http://localhost:63463/dart_sdk.js:170936:41)
at _engine.EnginePlatformDispatcher.__.[_sendPlatformMessage] (http://localhost:63463/dart_sdk.js:157234:39)
at _engine.EnginePlatformDispatcher.__.sendPlatformMessage (http://localhost:63463/dart_sdk.js:157101:33)
at _DefaultBinaryMessenger.[_sendPlatformMessage] (http://localhost:63463/packages/flutter/src/services/system_channels.dart.lib.js:2110:38)
at _DefaultBinaryMessenger.send (http://localhost:63463/packages/flutter/src/services/system_channels.dart.lib.js:2152:40)
at OptionalMethodChannel._invokeMethod (http://localhost:63463/packages/flutter/src/services/system_channels.dart.lib.js:938:50)
at _invokeMethod.next (<anonymous>)
at runBody (http://localhost:63463/dart_sdk.js:37422:34)
at Object._async [as async] (http://localhost:63463/dart_sdk.js:37453:7)
at OptionalMethodChannel.[_invokeMethod] (http://localhost:63463/packages/flutter/src/services/system_channels.dart.lib.js:936:20)
```

Widget inspector error - [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axaHk.png)

Comment: you have declared `late command;` variable but didn't initialized.

Comment: I havent declared any such variable though, I am also unable to find it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.